# Mac terminal command to list files and sort by date to use in ffmpeg

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, terminal

I am using a gopro to film a bunch of videos. I want to then take those videos directly from the SD card folder and concatenate them into a single video (bypass an editor) by using FFMPEG.

I'm currently able to stitch together "chaptered" videos with the following example command on my Mac (10.13):

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in /sdcardfolder/100GOPRO/GH*488.MP4; do echo "file '$f'"; done) -c copy /folder/video.mp4`

The reason for this is that the ffmpeg command requires a text file that looks like this:

> file '/folder/GH016992.MP4'
>
> file '/folder/GH036990.MP4'
>
> ...

The real command is this, which generates the list of files in the right format with `file` in front of each one and can be embedded into the `ffmpeg` command:

`for f in /Volumes/GoPro8/DCIM/100GOPRO/GH0*71*.MP4; do echo "file '$f'"; done`

I want to add 2 changes to this:

1. **List the files in date order (ascending):** I want the list of files to be in date order. But I can't figure out how to add a `-sort` or something to the `for f in` command.
2. **Allow a more robust set of file matching/filtering**: Right now I can add basic regex like `GH*488.MP4` or, with chapters which increments the first number, something like `GH0[123]488.MP4` would work to just get the first few. But when I change it to be more flexible like `GH0[0-9]71[0-9][0-9].MP4` - which would be necessary to match all files that were recorded yesterday, but nothing before then, the command doesn't like this regex. It seems to only accept a `*`.

I looked at a few examples like https://opensource.com/article/19/6/how-write-loop-bash but there wasn't much more than just listing files.

This boils down to a terminal command and isn't really related to FFMPEG but I hope it's helpful context.

I imagined it would be something like this, but this definitely doesn't work:

`for f in (find /Volumes/GoPro8/DCIM/100GOPRO/GH0[0-9]71[0-9][0-9].MP4 -type f | sort); do echo "file '$f'"; done`

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks!

**Update**

It looks like sorting isn't easy with Mac tools so I gave up and wrote a much simpler Ruby script that could execute everything for me. This is not really an answer to my question above but it is a solution.

Here I can easily write the text file necessary for ffmpeg and I can also filter files with a regex on the name, filter for a particular date, and size. Then, via the script, simply execute the ffmpeg command with args to concat files. I can also have it immediately resample the file to compress it (gopro videos are giant and I'm ok with a much lower bitrate if I want to save raw footage).

I got lucky with this `Dir.entries` in Ruby - it seems to automatically sort by date? I don't know how to sort it otherwise.

```
PATH = '/Volumes/GoPro8/DCIM/100GOPRO/'
NEW_FILENAME = '/folder/new-file.mp4'
video_list = '/folder/ffmpeg-list.txt'

# create the text file
File.delete(video_list) if File.exist?(video_list)
i = 1
Dir.entries(PATH).each do |f|
    d = File.mtime(PATH + f)
    size = File.size(PATH + f)
    if f.match(/GH0.*.MP4/) && d.to_s.match(/2020-07-30/) && size.to_i < 1000000000
        puts "#{i}\t#{f}\t#{d}\t#{size}"
        File.write(video_list, "file #{PATH + f}\n", mode: "a")
        i= i+1
    end
end

command = "ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i #{video_list} -c copy #{NEW_FILENAME}"

puts "executing concatenate..."
puts command
system(command)
```

Comment: So the files don't naturally ascend in numeric order? For the future, is there an option on your gopro to change the format of filenames used so you can have something including `2020-09-20-23:59:59` (or other self-sort format) ? Good luck.

Comment: Do the files have proper timestamps as seen from the file system? Then `ls -t` might be all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List and sort the files and iterate read each entry:

```sh
find /Volumes/GoPro8/DCIM/100GOPRO/ \
  -name 'GH0[0-9]71[0-9][0-9].MP4' \
  -type f \
  -printf '%A@\t%p\0' | sort -z -k1n | cut -z -f2- |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
    echo "$f"
  done
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm getting this error though

`find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

cut: illegal option -- z

usage: cut -b list [-n] [file ...]

       cut -c list [file ...]

       cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]`

Comment: @jeff Well, turns out these wonderful options are only available with the GNU CoreUtils. These are optionally installable on MacOS but available as default tools. The other alternative is the awful bad practice of parsing `ls` output. But I cannot recommend it at all. See: [stackexchange.com: How to replace Mac OS X utilities with GNU core utilities?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities)

Comment: ah yes I did a bit more sleuthing to find this article (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272491/bash-error-find-printf-unknown-primary-or-operator). Thank you!  I will attempt to install those tools...

Comment: Welp, I am not a pro at mac terminal stuff so I couldn't get the CoreUtils updated (and I got nervous as they warned about replacing these commands on the Mac) so I bailed. But as you can see above, I also bailed on the command line solution and opted for a Ruby script :)